# Create objects based on received data from params in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters

### Description

I am trying to create `messages` based on selected (via check box) `users` from the browser in Ruby on Rails.

Snapshot:
[image]

### Steps to reproduce

1. My schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_11_13_142255) do

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "role"
    t.integer "phone"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

2. messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @users = User.all

    @message = Message.new(message_params)
  end

  def create
    params[:user_objs].each do |u|
      # "params.inspect" returns
          # {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
          #  "user_objs"=>
          #   ["{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Alex\",\"role\":\"Engineer\",\"phone\":998943333303,\"admin\":true,\"created_at\":\"2021-11-13T14:37:54.962Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-11-13T14:37:54.962Z\"}",
          #    "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Lucy\",\"role\":\"Accountant\",\"phone\":998943333303,\"admin\":false,\"created_at\":\"2021-11-13T14:39:52.742Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2021-11-13T14:39:52.742Z\"}"],
          #  "message"=>{"content"=>"Message from the browser"},
          #  "commit"=>"Send"}
      person = JSON.parse(u)
      @message = person.messages.new(message_params)
      if @message.save
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        @users = User.all
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.permit(
        :content,
        :user_id
      )
  end
end
```

3. messages => new.html.erb

```
<div>
    <h1>Create and send a new message!</h1>

    <%= form_for(@message) do |form| %>
        <% if @message.errors.any? %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <h5 class="fw-bold">Invalid input!</h5>
                <%= @message.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
                    <div><%= error %></div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        
        <% @users.each do |u| %>
            <div>
                <p><%= check_box_tag "user_objs[]", u.to_json %> <%= u.name %></p>
            </div>
        <% end %>

        <p class="mb-3">
            <%= form.label :content, class: "form-label" %>
            <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control", autofocus: true, placeholder: "John_D" %>
        </p>

        <p class="mb-3">
            <%= form.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
<%= params.inspect %>
```

4. Models

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :messages
end


# message.rb
class Message < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

### Expected behavior

I was expecting the creation of messages for all selected users

### Actual behavior

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#create
undefined method `messages' for #<Hash:0x000000011fe2b420>
```

I tried different ways, but can't convert Ruby objects to `JSON` in my `params user_objs[]` so that I can parse it in my controller to create messages based on those selected users in the `user_objs[]` params.

### Environment info

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [arm64-darwin20]

rails -v
Rails 6.1.4.1
```

#### Thanks for any given help

Comment: The error is quite clear, you are trying to call `messages` on a `Hash` object. `@message = person.messages`, here `person` is a Hash because you called `person = JSON.parse`

Comment: You are also redirecting inside the loop so it will break on first iteration

Comment: @Eyeslandic thanks for the explanation. I will work on this direction and will update the results asap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to create a system where you send a single message to multiple users you would setup a join table:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_messages 
  has_many :recieved_messages, though: :user_messages,
                               source: :message,
                               inverse_of: :recipients
end
```

```
# rails g model user_message user:belongs_to message:belongs_to read:boolean
class UserMessage  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :message
  # make sure to add a compound unique index to the migration as well
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :message_id
  delegate :content, to: :message
end
```

```
class Message  < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_messages 
  has_many :recipients, though: :user_messages,
                        source: :user,
                        inverse_of: :recieved_messages
end
```

`has_many :recipients` will create a `recipient_ids=` setter and a `recipient_ids` getter that you can use in your form:

```
<div>
  <h1>Create and send a new message!</h1>

  <%= form_with(model: @message) do |form| %>
    <% if @message.errors.any? %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <h5 class="fw-bold">Invalid input!</h5>
          <%= @message.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
            <div><%= error %></div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <p class="mb-3">
      <%= form.collection_checkboxes(:recipient_ids, @users, :id, :name) %>
    </p>

    <p class="mb-3">
      <%= form.label :content, class: "form-label" %>
      <%= form.text_field :content, class: "form-control", autofocus: true, placeholder: "John_D" %>
    </p>

    <p class="mb-3">
      <%= form.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

There is absolutely no need to pass the entire record as JSON - you just pass an array of IDs and rails will do all the work of creating the join table rows for you:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @users = User.all
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @users = User.all
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message)
          .permit(
            :content,
            recipient_ids: []
          )
  end
end
```

This avoids the complexity of creating multiple records from a single request and the whole conundrum that you're binding the form to a single instance of Message but creating a bunch of records which is bound to lead to confusion.

If you want to create multiple records at once it can be done but the complexity is far higher and you have to deal with stuff like how to handle errors if creating one message fails and this might be beyond your current skill level.

Comment: PS. Setup the tabs in your editor to two spaces which is the standard for Ruby. This ain't Python and 4 spaces means you'll rapidly run out of space in a block based language.

Comment: thanks a lot for the given explanation. It is becoming obvious that I must practice on associations in the first place to properly digest the solution. I'd appreciate references/links to the useful resources concerning the associations if there is your favorite one in your mind

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are assigning a json object/hash in `person = JSON.parse(u)`. This is not an active record so when doing `person.messages` it throws the error. I believe what you need in the create action is something like:

```
user = JSON.parse(u)
# make sure user.inspect gives you the user object you want
person = User.find(user["id"])
# person.inspect should give you the active record for the user
```

Comment: This one was the easiest solution and it worked. I have got selected users' ids in the user_ids_params as an array. From there I can call each user in my controller, and then create a message to them. Currently, I can create a message object, but its content isn't being reflected somehow. I will update as soon as I find solution. But, making those operations (looping...) inside the controller is not the proper place. And they shall be solved in Model associations. Thanks, Victor